# AsyncPipe doesn't work for unknown reason

Tags: angular

Component:

```
loading: boolean = false;
loading$ = new Subject<boolean>();

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.loading$.subscribe(e => { this.loading = e; });
  ...
}
```

Template:

```
<div *ngIf="loading$ | async">
   <h1>Loading 1 ...</h1>
</div>

<div *ngIf="loading">
   <h1>Loading 2 ...</h1>
</div>
```

`Loading 2` appers, but `Loading 1` doesn't. What could be a reason?

Comment: Are you calling `this.loading$.next()` somewhere?

Comment: @SplitterAlex yes, otherwise `Loading 2` wouldn't have been appeared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your `loading$` subject does not have any initial value.

You need to either pass a value to your subject or use `BehaviorSubject`

First way:

```
loading: boolean = false;
loading$ = new Subject<boolean>();

constructor() {
  this.loading$.next(true);
}
```

Second way:

```
loading$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
```

For further reading:

https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-rxjs-behaviorsubject-replaysubject-and-asyncsubject-8cc061f1cfc0

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the subscription from the code - `async` will automatically do that.

```
loading: boolean = false;
loading$ = new Subject<boolean>();

ngOnInit(): void {

}
```

Comment: if I remove subscription, `Loading 2` stops appearing also. This subscribtion is needed here just for demonstration that the problem is on the AsyncPipe side.